# How to wrap pjsua-lib with Swig?

Tags: java, swig, pjsip

I'm trying to find a way to wrap the whole pjsua library into java classes with SWIG to use it on android. Does anyone have an experience in how to proceed?

Regards

Comment: I am facing same issue. i will let you if i find a solution. Same goes for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple, they have already created Java wrapper with SWIG.